# Using underdetermined system for dimensionality reduction.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an underdetermined linear system $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. I.e. A is $M$x$N$ and $M < N$.

Now, I want to be able to calculate $M$ of the values of $\vec{x}$ from the $N$-$M$ rest.
I know how to do this... But how does one best select which $M$ values?  The MxM matrix that I select needs to be invertible...

I basically want to be able to calculate $\vec{x} = V\vec{u} + \vec{v}$ where $\vec{u}$ has length $N-M$ and $\vec{x}$ has length $N$. Are there any other ways to achieve this?

I am basically trying to solve a constrained optimization problem. I know I can use Lagrange multipliers, but I want to do it by reducing dimensionality directly.

Comment: You could use $QR$.

Comment: How would one do that?

Comment: You need to do some work yourself. Try Googling "qr null space". https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2511/26983

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with null space @copper.hat

Found a solution that I think is satisfactory. It seems to work, but I haven't tested it thoroughly, yet. Please, anyone, let me know of any potential pitfalls.

### Solution

1. Calculate an arbitrary solution to $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$. For instance the least-squares solution found using the pseudoinverse. $\vec{x_0} = A^+\vec{b}$.
2. Calculate the nullspace matrix $Z$, which has shape $N$x$(N-rank(A))$.
3. Now you can calculate $\vec{x} = Z\vec{u} + \vec{x_0}$.

If rows in A are linearly independent, then $rank(A) = M$. But the null_space() calculation in SciPy will handle this automatically.

Comment: Looks reasonable. Keep in mind that there are almost always some numerical errors, so keep that in mind with your subsequent use of $Zu+x_0$.

Comment: Thanks. I see that null_space calculated with SVD vs QR is different. Both sets of vectors are orthogonal bases and are normed to 1. They are quite similar, but not exactly the same... Is this normal? Or result of the numerical instability?

Can you point me in direction of more info on the numerical instability?

Would you say lagrange multipliers will give more accurate results if I was going to use this for implementing linear equality constraints in a quadratic optimization problem?

Comment: How do you know the null spaces are different?

Comment: The numerical values in the actual Z matrices calculated with the two different methods are slightly different.  If the actual space spanned by these vectors are different I dont know.  Probably not.

Both versions give the correct answer for the optimization problem I am solving.  The values for u is different, but the calculated value for x is the same.

Comment: There is no a priori reason to expect that the basis will be the same, but it is easy to check that both span the kernel.